# How to read and compare character 255 in C

Tags: c, string, compare, character, eof

I need to write a code that searches all the aparition of a string in a file. Recently, my teacher told me to search string (char)255(char)255 in a file with the same string. The problem is that I can not read those characters and badly, I cannot distinguish or compare those caracter to EOF; My code for searching the given string in a file is :

```
//problema 14

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char b;
    int k=0;
    if(argc!=3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Utilizare: %s fisier sir\n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
        }  
    if(argv[2][0]=='\0'){
        fprintf(stderr, "String vid\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *f;
    f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (!f)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }


    int i=0;

    while((b = fgetc(f))!=EOF)
    {

        if(b==argv[2][i]) i++;
        else {
            fseek(f,-i, SEEK_CUR);
            i=0;
        }

        if(argv[2][i]=='\0'){
            k++;
            fseek(f,-i+1, SEEK_CUR);
            i=0;
        }



    }
    printf("\nSULFUS %d APPEARANCES\n",k);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

what can I do with this code to work on comparint string of (char)255 characters?

Comment: Why would your teacher ask you to do such a thing? Character code `255` usually isn't valid, so you can't expect a C program to handles that correctly.

Comment: @JensGustedt One definitely can and should expect a C program to handle the full range of characters, from zero to 255, inclusive. That's the reason the library designers went with `fgetc` returning an `int`, even though it reads a `char`.

Comment: EOF is 0xFFFFFFFF (and integer value of -1) the line: 'char b;' should be 'int b;'  Then the value returned from fgetc() can be properly compared and a 8bit char, when returned, can be manipulated as a possible 0xFF

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, no, if `char` is signed `255` normally lays outside the range of `char`, and then `(char)255` is implementation defined behavior, certainly nothing that should be taught at this level of understanding of C.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to realize that `fgetc` returns an `int`.

So, change the data type of `b`to `int`!

Comment: ... and `fgetc` converts the character read to an `unsigned char`, which may cause trouble in `if(b==argv[2][i])` if `char` is signed.

Answer (score 1):

But then, "while" does nothing, because it seems that 255 is also recognized as EOF or it goes infinite. I tried also with int but I couldn't figure out much...This teacher is like a compilator, he likes to put you in trouble.

Comment: Use comments, edit your question, or ask a new question (not in this case) to request clarification. Answers are intended to be answers.